# Datatable is getting applied but not functioning

Tags: jquery, datatables, flyout

I am using one plugin called flyout. Below is the link of plugin to show table as flyout.

https://www.jqueryscript.net/tooltip/Simple-Customizable-Tooltip-Popover-Plugin-Flyout.html

At the same time I am using jQuery DataTables for table inside flyout.
below is my code

```
<div id="ShowActiveEngagements" class="hide">     
    <table #dataTable id="EngagementDatatableId" class="DataList table EngagementDatatable">
        <thead>
           <tr>
            <td>abc</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>Mohini</td>
            <td>Agrrement</td>
            <td>7/5/2019</td>
            <td>Go to Workspace</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
</div>
```

Here datatable is getting applied when I open popup but it's not functioning. When i click on sort or paging its not working. See below jQuery code which I am using.

```
$('.EngagementDatatable').DataTable({
      bLengthChange: false,
      searching: false,
      iDisplayLength: 2
      // "paging": true,
      // "bPaginate": true
});

$('#ViewEngagements').flyout({
      title: 'Active Engagements(5)',
      placement: 'right',
      content: $("#ShowActiveEngagements").html(),
      html: true
});
```

can anyone please help to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using `html()` returns a new table as raw html  that is not initialized by the datatables plugin

Comment: @charlietfl I am returning content of div by using html().